# iterate over array and assign values to columns in table - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I'm new to javascript. Please help me out with the below question.

I have a table defined.

```
<div id="SampleDiv">
   <table id="SampleTable">
     <tr>
       <td></td>       
     </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I have an dynamic array defined
 var SampleArr = ["Hello","Welcome","Folks",....];

Question : How do i loop this array and assign values to the td's in the table?

desired output::

```
<div id="SampleDiv">
   <table id="SampleTable">
     <tr>
       <td>Hello</td> 
       <td>Welcome</td>   
       <td>Folks</td>
       ....         
     </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Using jQuery: `$.each( SampleArr, function(){})`, using vanilla JS: `SampleArr.forEach(function(){})`.

Comment: Can you give me an example

Comment: Do you need this to be done in jQuery?

Comment: @user724747 I have provided some pointers, show some effort first.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery solution:

```
  $.each(SampleArr, function(index, value) {

    $('#SampleTable td:last').after('<td>'+value+'</td>');

  });
```

Comment: Hi tried this ..consider i have table like this    <div id="SampleDiv">
   <table id="SampleTable">
     <tr>
         <td><label>First Name:</label></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>       
         <td><label>Middle Name:</label></td>               
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td><label>Last Name:</label></td>
       </tr>
     
</table>
</div>  and array as ["Fname","Mname","Lname"]; ..I get output as this http://jsfiddle.net/chandrapraba/Lxbjqyed/5/

Answer (score 1):

I have tried using jQuery. I hope it may help you.

```
HTML:-

<table id="mytable">
  <tr><td><label>First Name : </label></td></tr>
  <tr><td><label>Middle Name : </label></td></tr>
  <tr><td><label>Last Name : </label></td></tr>
</table>

-----------

JQuery:-

var data = ["Krishna","Kant","Shastri"];  //first name, midle name, last name

//get all <td> element
var myTD = $('#mytable td');

//iterate all <td> and append values from data array
$.each(myTD,function(idx,tdHTML){
  $(tdHTML).append(data[idx]);
});

----------
Output:-
First Name : Krishna
Middle Name : Kant
Last Name : Shastri
```

make sure data array should have details in order first name, middle name & last name.
You can also store both label and values in same array and populate.

### Thanks

If you dont know how many data is there in array than try storing label and value in json and populate like this:-

```
HTML:-

<table id="mytable">
</table>

jquery:-

var data = {"First Name":"Krishna", "Middle Name":"Kant", "Last Name":"Shastri", "Place":"India"};

var tableHTML = '';

$.each(data,function(key,value){
  tableHTML += '<tr><td><label>'+ key +' : '+ value +'</label></td></tr>';
});
$('#mytable').html(tableHTML);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is some vanilla javascript to use:

```js
var SampleArr = ["Hello","Welcome","Folks"];

var html = '<div id="SampleDiv"><table id="SampleTable"><tr>';

for (var i=0,max=SampleArr.length;i<max;i++) {
 html += '<td>'+SampleArr[i]+'</td>';  
}
html += '</tr></table></div>';
document.write(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here man:

```
var template = null;
var array = ['leo', 'Liz', 'Michael'];

for(var i =0; i<array.length; i++){
    template = '<tr><td>' + array[i] + '</td></tr>';
    $('table').append(template);
}
```

**here is a functional example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/gfduxa42/

Comment: This doesn't match the desired output ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the JavaScripts `forEach()` loop to keep this in plain JS.

```js
var sampleArr = ["Hello,", "Welcome", "to", "the", "jungle"];

var tableRow = document.getElementById("row1");

sampleArr.forEach(function(value){
  tableRow.innerHTML += "<td>" + value + "</td>";
});
```

```html
<table id="t-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="row1"></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

And the solution Pure Javascript and DOM manipulation *(without 5Go framework)*:

```js
var SampleArr = ["Hello","Welcome","Folks"];
var table = document.getElementById('SampleTable');

SampleArr.forEach(function(val  , i){

  var curCell = table.rows[0].cells[i];
  if(!curCell) curCell = table.rows[0].insertCell();

   var curValue = curCell.innerText || curCell.textContent;

   curCell.innerHTML = curValue + val;
})
```

```html
<div id="SampleDiv">
   <table id="SampleTable" border=1>
     <tr>
       <td>First Name : </td>       
       <td>Middle Name : </td>       
       <td>Last Name : </td>       
     </tr>
</table>
</div>
```